# Can “ liquid music” refer to “downloadable music”?

Tags: expressions, american-english, british-english, neologisms

The recent Italian expression “[musica liquida](https://it.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musica_liquida)” (liquid music) has been used  for about a decade now referring to the music which is no longer  recorded on traditional devices such as records, CDs  or tapes, but which is easily and freely available on the net.

The expression was originally used in very specialized magazines which focus on  devises for recording or reproducing sounds and music.

[image: enter image description sere]

Given the tendency of  Italians to adopt English terms, especially in the field of new technologies, I feel that the expression may have been derived from American or English expressions, but I couldn’t find any evidence to support my impression. And actually [liquid](https://www.google.com/search?safe=strict&rlz=1C9BKJA_enIT753IT753&hl=it&ei=G2W_XOePA43gkgWwvpuQBA&q=liquid%20%20meaning&oq=liquid%20%20meaning&gs_l=mobile-gws-wiz-serp.3..0i7i30i19j0i19j0i7i30i19l6.6453.6990..7460...0.0..0.150.618.0j5......0....1.........0i7i30j0i8i7i30.HgeDFGLqa5g), referring to music,  appears to have a different connotation in English:

> (of a sound) clear, pure, and flowing; harmonious.
>   "the liquid song of the birds"

So, is liquid music used also in the sense of “downloadable music” in English? If not what expression is used in that context?

Comment: Hello, Mary-Lou A...where are you? I think you are probably the best qualified to answer this.

Comment: i've never heard of music being described as liquid, but i've heard of funds being described as liquid. a liquid is of course something that can move around almost beyond your control unless you contain it. im guessing this is not of english origin, though not necessarily of italian origin, in reference to the high portability of digital music, which is as you put it:  "easily and freely available on the net"

Comment: If this were a loanword from English, then it would be "liquid music". The fact that the term is in Italian (and does not exist in English) suggests it is an Italian neologism. (The only English article I could find using the term "liquid music" was written by an Italian: http://www.maxresearch.com/tecnology/liquid-music-part-1/)